# How to get last ID of ul>li item with jquery and add a new item with new id

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic nested list
for example

```
<ul id="mylist" class="mylist">
  <li id="p-1">Item</li>
   <ul>
     <li id="p-3">Sub-Item</li>
        ( ...maybe more sub-elements)
   </ul>
  <li id="p-2">Item</li>
  <li id="p-3">Item</li>
...
</ul>
```

How I can get the last (highest) ID of "li" Element inside the main-ul with class `mylist` (including the elements of the other nested ul lists)?

Trie to do it in this way failed

```
$(".addnew-listitem").click(function() {
var $div = $("ul#mylist > li[id^=\'p-\']:last");
var newnum = parseInt( $div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;
var newItem = $("#"+$(this).data("orderunder")).clone(true).prop("id", "p-"+newnum );
 var $check = $("ul#mylist > li[id^=\'p-\']:last");
 $(newItem).appendTo("#"+$(this).data("orderunder"));
  $(".mylist").sortable("refresh");
});
```

If a load the page and add one new item, i get the correct next id (4).
Also the new item is correctly added with the new id p-4.
**If i want to add a second one, i recieve the old, last id 4 again, what i do wrong at this?**

Thanks for explaning how it works!

Comment: have you tried anything on your end first? If yes, then please post it otherwise try on your own first and then post it

Comment: :-) i've update the post

Comment: @caro please show what  you have tried so far. Nobody here to homework for you.

Comment: The `id` attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below -
Where you can use `>` to get direct child and not child of child and use `:last` to get last matching `li`

```js
$(function(){
    var $div = $("ul.mylist > li[id^=\'p-\']:last");
    alert($div.text()); // for text
    alert($div.attr('id')); // for id
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="mylist">
   <li id="p-1">Item p-1</li>
    <ul>
      <li id="p-3">Sub-Item sub-3</li>
        ( ...maybe more sub-elements)
   </ul>
 <li id="p-2">Item p-2</li>
 <li id="p-3">Item p-3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks a lot,, for me it outputs the Item text and not the id, what can it caused?

Comment: you need to use `attr('id')` on $div to get the id of last li. Please see my updated post

Comment: :-) ok, i understand, have a idear why i get the old latest id after i add a new item? Please have a look at my updated post

Comment: what is the value of `$(this).data("orderunder")`? can you add add new item html also so that i can take a look at it

Comment: oderunder is the id from the upper element. a new item should add under this element, this part works...